# How to make the input text wider

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I trying to make the text bar wider but I cant get it to work. I have tried with `width` but it didn't work for me. I also couldn't find anything on the internet.

This is my `HTML`:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<legend>Neem contact op</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="Naam">Naam: </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Naam" name="Naam" placeholder="Naam" required="required" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="Email">Email :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" id="Email"name="Email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="Seizoen">Seizoen: </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="Seizoen" id="Seizoen" required>
            <option value="">Kies hier je seizoen</option>
                <option value="Lente">Lente</option>
                <option value="Zomer">Zomer</option>
                <option value="Herfst">Herfst</option>
                <option value="Winter">Winter</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <hr />  
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="Benodigheden">Benodigheden:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Benodigheden"name="Benodigheden" placeholder="Benodigheden" required="required" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="Opmerking">Opmerking:</label>
            </td>
        <td>
            <textarea name="Opmerking" id="Opmerking" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Opmerking" required="required" /></textarea>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Verzenden" name="Verzenden" /></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ab0095tm/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only wish to make input-type="text" have a certain width, add this style in your css file fx:

```
input[type=text] {
   width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

While the above code is very good, minimal and clean, which is best. But IF you need different widths for each of your text inputs then inline CSS is needed.

Example code:

```
<input style="width: 300px;" type="text">
<input style="width: 340px;" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

add some css to the head section of your html

```
<style>
input{width: 300px}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your table wider.

Add desired width to your td's

Ajust your inputs widht.